SQL query that returns results that have all tags, not any
I have three tables:
A table of plays (tbl_plays), a table of possible tags (tbl_tags), and a table of applied tags (tbl_tagged) each play may have one or more tags applied to it e.g.
'Three Blind Mice' is tagged 'Children's theatre'
'50 Shade of Grey, the Musical' is tagged 'Musical Theatre' and 'Adult Content'
'Narnia, a Musical Play' is tagged 'Children's Theatre' and 'Musical Theatre'
I'm trying to build a query that returns only those plays that have ALL selected tags (e.g. if the user selects 'Children's theatre', the result should contain both 'Three Blind Mice' and 'Narnia, a Musical Play', but should omit '50 Shades of Grey, the Musical', but if they select both 'Children's Theatre' and 'Musical Theatre', the result should only contain 'Narnia, a Musical Play' and should NOT contain both 'Three Blind Mice' and '50 Shades of Grey, the Musical').
My current query is returning incorrect results. Here is my current query, and the table structure is illustrated below that.
I am using PHP 8.3.14 and querying using MySQLi
SQL Query:
SELECT DISTINCT 
     tbl_plays.play_ID,
     tbl_plays.play_title,
     tbl_tagged.tag_ID
FROM
     tbl_plays
INNER JOIN tbl_tagged ON tbl_plays.play_ID = tbl_tagged.play_ID
WHERE
     tbl_tagged.tag_ID IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
     tbl_plays.play_ID
HAVING
     COUNT(1) = 2

SQL Table Structure:
tbl_plays (play_ID, play_title)
tbl_tags (tag_ID, tag_name)
tbl_tagged (tagged_ID, play_ID, tag_ID)
so, for instance, tbl_plays:



play_ID
play_title




1
Three Blind Mice


2
50 Shades of Grey, the Musical


3
Narnia, a Musical Play



tbl_tags:



tag_ID
tag_name




1
Children's Theatre


2
Musical Theatre


3
Adult Content



tbl_tagged:



tagged_ID
play_ID
tag_ID




1
1
1


2
2
2


3
2
3


4
3
1


5
3
3




Your SQL works fine for me (after i change the selection criteria from (1, 2) to a scenario that actually exists in your sample data. see here

What does this have to do with PHP?

Combing SELECT DISTINCT and GROUP BY is very rarely correct.

You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT - except those who are arguments to aggregate functions.

Sample data is great, but a [mcve] is also supposed to specify the expected result.

There is no question in this post.

Please either ask about bad code with the obligatory [mre] & why you
think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it
doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative
documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you
can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because
misconceptions will get in the way of understanding the latter. [ask] [Help]
